# Initial Value Problem of Difrrential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y(x)$ be continuous solution of initial value problem $\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=f(x),y(0)=0$.

Where $f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
1 & \mbox{for}
& 0 \leq x\leq 1 \\ 0 & \mbox{for} & x>1 
\end{array}\right.$

Then FInd $y(\frac{3}{2})$

Answer is $\frac{sinh(1)}{e^2}$

I have tried the following:

It is a linear differential equation

$\therefore $Multiplying each term by $e^{\int 2dx}=e^{2x}$

$\therefore \frac{d}{dx}\left(y.e^{2x}\right)=e^{2x}f(x)$

$\therefore y(e^{2x})=\int e^{2x}.f(x) dx$

$\therefore y=e^{-2x}\int e^{2x}.f(x).dx$

Comment: Ok, I agree :) Was there anything else that you've wanted to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have correctly calculated

$$ ye^{2x}=\int e^{2x}.f(x).dx$$.

Now $$[y e^{2x}]_{0}^{3/2}=\int_{0}^{3/2} e^{2x}.f(x).dx$$
$$e^3y(3/2)-e^0y(0)=\int_{0}^{1} e^{2x}dx$$
$$y(3/2)=e^{-3}\int_{0}^{1} e^{2x}dx$$

After integration

$$y(3/2)=e^{-3}\frac{e^2-1}{2}$$

Few manipulation and using the definition of $\sinh(x)$ we get

$$y(3/2)=\frac{\sinh(1)}{e^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

I have given hand-written solution and hope this helps.  If you have any question leave me a comment. Goodluck
[image]